# Disable yellow text highlighting in PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

When I use PyCharm terminal sometimes my text is highlighting in yellow color and it's annoying. How can I disable it? Example:
[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html#smart-command-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to see this link for disabling

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html#smart-command-execution